# Instance member 'addNumbers' can't be accessed using static

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

i try to create a function to simply add a data to list
this is my function implementation

```
void addNumbers() {

    numbers.add(numberController.value);
    numberController.clear();
    print(numbers);

  }
```

this is view page

```
Obx((){
       return RaisedButton(
                child: Text("ADD",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                onPressed: MessageContoller.addNumbers(),
              ); 
      });
```

> but it show to error like "Instance member 'addNumbers' can't be
> accessed using static"

Comment: You need to call `addNumbers()` on an instance of the controller. I don't know if you already have that without seeing the rest of the file, but maybe you have it defined with a lowercase letter like `messageContoller` and then do `messageContoller.addNumbers()`

Comment: sorry i corrected that i it show another error like   `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.`

Comment: Then try to write it as `onPressed: ()=>messageContoller.addNumbers(),`

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of MessageController in your Stateful/stateless widget
like
`MessageController messageController = Get.put(MessageController())`
Then use it like messageController.addNumbers() on your button onTap